# Are Night Parrots (Pezoporus occidentalis) really extinct?

Tags: zoology, ornithology

This incredibly rare animal has been reported to be extinct since 1990, however several cases has been raised that night parrot was spotted in the areas of Australia. What is the cause of their extinction, or in the first place, are they really extinct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_Parrot#cite_note-ag-16) it is listed as endangered having been downgraded from critically endangered due to the spread in sightings over the years over a large area. Sightings have been rare with a reported sighting on [12th April 2005](http://www.publish.csiro.au/?paper=MU07058) and a dead specimen found [in 2006](http://scienceblogs.com/tetrapodzoology/2009/10/06/2006-dead-night-parrot/) The first photos and a 17 second video of the bird was taken by a wildlife photographer [John Young](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Young_%28cinematographer%29) in 2013. Details can be found in [this link](http://www.australiangeographic.com.au/news/2013/07/night-parrot-tantalising-clues-revealed/).

According to [Birdlife.org](http://www.birdlife.org/datazone/speciesfactsheet.php?id=1491) the reason for its population to decrease significantly include predation by feral cats and foxes, altered fire regimes, competition for food, degradation of habitat near water by stock or rabbits, and reduced availability of water as a result of over-use by feral camels.

Comment: At least they are not extinct.. That solves!